# How do I reference the ApplicationEventPublisher in SpEL?

Tags: java, spring, events, spring-el, spring-ioc

I am wanting to publish an application event using `ApplicationEventPublisher#publishEvent()` from a Spring Web Flow step. The publisher is usually the application context, but I'd rather not make that assumption unless necessary (particularly for mocking). Is there a recommended approach for referring to the publisher object from a SpEL expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "inject" the publisher into a SpEL expression, like you would with a bean.

Add a custom bean to the context that is `ApplicationEventPublisherAware`; add a getter and use `@bean.publisher.publishEvent(...)`.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use the interface these days instead of just injecting the `ApplicationEventPublisher` into the bean directly?

Comment: Not sure what you mean; with the interface, Spring takes care of injecting the publisher. `@Autowired` would work too but if you're not using annotation-driven config, you need to implement the interface.

Comment: I already have a Groovy trait that I'm using to wire it in where needed, and I was planning to use `class EventPublisherHolder implements Auditing {}`.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem recently. I needed to call the function from SpEL expression on the object of specific type (essentially auto-wired into the expression itself). Unfortunately look like SpEL does not support it so I had to choose between two options:

1. Call from expression using bean reference and ensure that I register bean with this name in context - `@myBean.someMethod()`
2. Implement and register custom SpEL function and inject bean by type there. Then call the function from your expression - `#someFunction()`

I think the second approach might be more appropriate in your situation as you have quite generic functionality that could be used throughout the app. You would also be able to unit test the function as well as mock the target `ApplicationEventPublisher` instance easily.

Please refer to the Spring SpEL [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-ref-functions) for details on the function registration.

Comment: The difficulty with the first is that the bean I want is usually the `ApplicationContext` itself, and there's no equivalent of not-`@Primary`; I really don't want to break things by having duplicate copies of the context bean! As far as the second goes, it's not practical to register custom functions with an evaluation context that I don't own, such as the context managed by SWF.

Comment: You could create bean with predefined id (e.g. `publisher`), inject into this bean dependency on `ApplicationEventPublisher` and implement method that simply delegates to `publishEvent`. Then you will reference this bean by id using `@publisher` notation. When you want to mock functionality to will mock `publisher` instance. This way you will have full control.